# Can I see which Jecht Spheres I've already collected?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I'm playing FFX HD, and currently going back to collect Jecht Spheres. I've obviously missed one somewhere as I don't have the trophy or Auron's final overdrive, but looking at a guide I'm not sure which one.

Is there a way to see which Jecht Spheres I've already collected, so I can more easily determine which one I've missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, short of making a checklist beforehand, or revisiting each area, there is no way to tell which ones you have or haven't got.

The exception is the very first Jecht Sphere you receive. You will always be given one after defeating Spherimorph. The rest you'll have to log manually, or mentally, otherwise you'll just have to go to the areas listed in the guide to see for yourself.

Comment: That's a shame. I eventually found it by forcing myself to recheck every area on the list again - thanks for your help.